# systemd: cpu usage of services

Tags: arch-linux, cpu-usage, systemd

I'm running `systemd 229-3` on an up-to-date Arch Linux installation. Lightdm is launched on startup, and starts my XFCE desktop environment. Furthermore, `laptop-mode-tools` is installed and run on startup.

Sometimes, after logging in, I experience huge reaction times on my system, and I already noticed a couple of times, that `systemd` with high CPU usage is causing them. **How can I figure out, what service is the reason of that high CPU usage?** I've already tried to disable `laptop-mode.service`, but to no avail. There must be a way to see what service is causing trouble here, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enabled the `cpuacct` cgroup subgroup in the kernel. You can try `systemd-cgtop` to identify which systemd service causes high cpu usage.

Generally `top` can be used to check the cpu usage by each process.

Comment: Of course I'm using `top` to monitor my system's activity, but it just shows `systemd` with a stunning high CPU usage (up to 300%). I'll give `systemd-cgtop` a try the next time I notice this issue ;) Thanks so far.